# Float:Right on one list item not working

Tags: html, css, nav

[image: The Error]

So I'm getting the above error by trying to `float:right;` the `Login/Signup` link. I can't seem to get it working with my current setup. I have tried floating it left but it ends up just putting the `li` in standard order with 100% width. I was wondering if I'm being an idiot with `css` and can't do something simple like this. The goal is to make the last `<li>` sit against the right

The Code: HTML

```
    <div id="mainNav">
    <nav class="myNav">
        <ul class="myNavBar">
            <li>
                <a href="index.html">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="user.html">Sample User</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="jobs.html">Sample Jobs</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="findcom.html">Sample Find</a>
            </li>
            <li class="right-align">
                <a href="login.html">Login/Signup</a>
            </li>
            <br class="clearBoth"/>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
```

The Code: CSS

```
.myNav {
    padding: 15px;
    margin: 0;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    background-color: #81A7ED;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}

.myNavBar {
    list-style-type: none;
    width: 100%;
    margin-right: 15px;
    margin-left:15px;
}

.myNavBar > li {
    display: inline;
    width: 100%;
}

.myNavBar > li > a {
    color: #0C3A8E;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-bottom: solid 2px #81A7ED;
    padding-left: 1%;
    padding-right: 1%;
    padding-top: 7px;
    padding-bottom: 7px;
    font-size: small;
    transition: border-bottom .25s;
}

.myNavBar > li > a:hover {
    border-bottom: solid 2px #0C3A8E;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: border-bottom .25s;
}
.myNavBar > .right-align {
    float:right;
}
```

I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have set for some reason `width: 100%;` to your LI elements

also `<br class="clearBoth"/>` is not a valid children of `UL` :)

**[jsBin](http://jsbin.com/komot/3/edit)**

Modified HTML:

```
<ul class="myNavBar cf">
```

Your edited CSS with notes:

```
*{padding:0; margin:0;} /* Do you use some CSS reset? */
a{  text-decoration: none; }
/* Clearfix   http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/ */
.cf:before,
.cf:after {
    content: " "; /* 1 */
    display: table; /* 2 */
}
.cf:after { clear: both; }
/* Used to clear floats */


/* Now... */
nav.myNav {
    padding: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    background-color: #81A7ED;
}

ul.myNavBar {
    list-style: none;
    /*width: 100%; it's already "100%" by defalt*/
    /* ??? 100% and than margin? 
    margin-right: 15px; 
    margin-left:15px;
    */
}
ul.myNavBar > li {
    float:left;
    /*width: 100%; why 100? */
}
ul.myNavBar > li > a {
    display: inline-block; /* Note this !*/
    color: #0C3A8E;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-bottom: solid 2px #81A7ED;
    padding: 7px 15%; /* Note this */
    font-size: small;
    transition: border-bottom .25s;
}
ul.myNavBar > li > a:hover {
    border-bottom: solid 2px #0C3A8E;
    /*transition: border-bottom .25s;  is already defined! */
}
.myNavBar > .right-align {
    float:right;
}
```

Comment: I would like to say I facepalm in your name and appreciate everything I am given in this world. Thank you.

Comment: That still leaves a large gap between the last <li> and the rest.

Comment: Right, I wanted to Align the last <li> to the right so I can have some seperation from the rest

Comment: @user1449940 I've edited completely your CSS. Note my comments, hope will be useful.

Comment: @AliGajani there was so many things wrong in the OP's code that I needed more time than you might think to write my answer. Thanks though for the comment

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the class

```
class="right-align"
```

from the said li element. And your code will work as you want.

Comment: I wasn't specific enough, sorry. Here's an upvote for answering the original problem.

Comment: There's much more things OP needs to fix than just plain remove a *class*.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is remove the:
    .myNavBar > .right-align {
    float:right;
    }

Answer (score 0):

Just remove these lines in CSS file:

```
.myNavBar {
    width: 100%;
}

.myNavBar > li {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Also, its better to put the floating `<li>` as the first `<li>` element in the `<ul>`

```
<ul class="myNavBar">
    <li class="right-align">
        <a href="login.html">Login/Signup</a>
    </li>
    <li>...</li>
</ul>
```